# Good examples of traversing/transforming expression trees

Tags: c#, linq

I guess the title says what I'm looking for. Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

I have entities (some of them generated at runtime with CodeDom)

```
public abstract class Content
{
    public virtual Page Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Property> Properties { get; set; }
    // T GetPropertyValue<T>(string)
    // SetPropertyValue(string, object)
}
public abstract class Page : Content
{
    public virtual string Path { get; set; }
}
// Generated with CodeDom
public class Post : Page
{
    public virtual string Text 
    { 
        get
        {
            // get value from Properties
            return GetPropertyValue<string>("Text");
        }   
        set
        {
            // set value to Properties
            SetPropertyValue("Text", value);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using NHibernate to query items.
Problem: I can't use `Post.Text` in Where clause.
Solution: Create own extension method which transforms lambda expressions to another format.

E.g query

```
var posts = session.Query<Post>().Filter(p => 
    p.Parent.Path.StartsWith("/blogs/programming/") && 
    p.Text.Contains("hello"));
```

could be transformed to either of the following

```
public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterExpr)
{
    return query.Where(p => 
        p.Parent.Path.StartsWith("/blogs/programming/") &&
        p.Properties.OfType<StringProperty>().Any(p2 => 
            p2.Name == "Text" && 
            p2.StringValue.Contains("hello")));
}

public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterExpr)
{
    var ids1 = session.Query<Content>().Where(p => 
                p.Parent.Path.StartsWith("/blogs/programming/"))
                .Select(p => p.Id);
    var ids2 = session.Query<StringProperty>().Where(p => 
                p.Name == "Text" && 
                p.StringValue.Contains("hello"))
                .Select(p => p.Content.Id);
    var ids = ids1.Intersect(ids2);
    return query.Where(p => ids.Contains(p.Id));
}
```

Any good non-trivial examples or open source projects?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could take a look at Brahma, my LINQ to OpenCL translator. http://brahma.codeolex.com

It does something my very similar to what you want to achieve.

Hope this helps!